# How can I auto-format org-mode to have a newline in between TODOs?

Tags: org-mode, formatting

In `org-mode` I have following `TODOs`:

```
* TODO task1
do this
* TODO task2
do that
* TODO task3
```

Would it be possible to `auto-format` it to have new-line in between `TODOs` as:

```
* TODO task1
do this

* TODO task2
do that

* TODO task3
```

I can do this operation manually but I have hundreds of `TODOs` in my file, its hard to organize them.

---

The way I insert `TODO` is with following function:

```lisp
(defun insert-todo ()
  (interactive "*")
  (insert comment-start "TODO: "))
```

Comment: See https://github.com/alphapapa/unpackaged.el#ensure-blank-lines-between-headings-and-before-contents

Comment: Should I look into `unpackaged/caps-to-code` function?

Comment: The link points to `unpackaged/org-fix-blank-lines`.

Comment: Would it be enough if I just run `unpackaged/org-fix-blank-lines` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about all headlines or just headlines with a TODO keyword? In the first case, customize `org-blank-before-new-entry` and make its `heading` value to be `t`, instead of `auto`:

```
(setq org-blank-before-new-entry '((heading . t) (plain-list-item . auto)))
```

If you want empty lines before plain list items as well, change the `plain-list-item` value to `t`.

This assumes that you are using standard Org mode functions to insert things: `org-insert-headline` and `org-insert-item`. Both of those are available through the context-dependent keybinding `M-RET`.

If you are talking about headlines with TODO keywords only, there is nothing that I know of to do that. And given that a headline can get a TODO keyword (or lose it) with a call to `org-todo`, it seems to me that having an empty line added or taken away automatically in this case would be more harmful than helpful. You could modify `org-todo` to add or delete blank lines, but at least for me, it would drive me up the wall.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about all the headlines, since I was just using `TODO` it does not matter much. Having `org-blank-before-new-entry`did not add any newline, should I call any additional funciton?

Comment: Do you create your headlines with `M-RET` (bound to `org-meta-return`) or manually by typing asterisks? Try the former method.

Comment: I added the function I was using into my question, it was just pasting `** TODO` string

Comment: There are advantages to using standard methods as provided by Org mode. I would recommend you change to `M-RET` to insert a headline and `C-c C-t` to mark it as a TODO item (wiith subsequent `C-c C-t` presses stepping you through the various TODO states).  As for your function, it does not work for me at all: it inserts a commented `TODO:`, not a headline.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>M-<</kbd> ; start of buffer

<kbd>C-M-%</kbd> ; query-replace-regexp

<kbd>^ \ * RET</kbd> ; look for lines starting with "*"

<kbd>C-q C-j * RET</kbd> ; add a leading newline to matching lines

<kbd>!</kbd> ; apply to the whole file

Comment: Could this be done as a function, where called after each save?

Comment: Absolutely. Just look up (`C-h k`) the functions bound to those keys and put them in order. Don't forget to put `(interactive)` first.

Comment: Should I wtype `RET` into string as well right?

Comment: No, `RET` means type the enter/return key.

Comment: BTW note that the answer was not displaying the backslash before the first asterisk previously. I've updated it so it does show that now.

Comment: And also note that no backslash is required before the second asterisk.